# Unable to Find Metadata DLL VS 2019 Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

There are lots of solutions here on stackoverflow. But none of these helped solve this problem.

I've tried **Clean Solution** > **Rebuild Solution** > **Restarted VS 2019** > **Run as Admin**

I've also tried Checking and Unchecking the Checkboxes in Configuration Manager, and still doesn't help.

All of my Libraries are now up to date, even VS 2019 is up to date, but still no luck.

I've also checked if i'm having a bad code somewhere in my project, I found some, but just commented it out, thinking it may be the problem of my project, still no luck.

Errors keeps prompting.

"Metadata file "projectname.dll" could not be found."
"Csc.exe exited with code -2146232797"

Comment: You could report the issue : Help -> Send Feedback->Report a problem .

Comment: error is 0x80131623 = COR_E_FAILFAST Runtime operation halted by call to System.Environment.FailFast(). So C# compiler run into an issue. does it happen to all xamarin apps or only 1 specific one?

Comment: I don't get what you mean about all xamarin apps. But it prompts an error on both IOS and Android DLL's, stating the both metadata file "appname.dll" are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I've found the issue.

There was this line of code that made the error.

I have an object of string array.

and I tried getting the last index by using

```
stringArray[stringArray.Length - 1]
```

After, I tried highlighting the code, and VS2019 Suggested in using index operators.

So the code transformed from:

```
stringArray[stringArray.Length - 1]
```

to:

```
stringArray[^1]
```

And that's when the error "csc.exe exited with a code -2146232797" prompted.

I tried going back the old way.

```
stringArray[stringArray.Length - 1]
```

And it finally worked.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer , which will help more people :)